# Валидация интервала дат

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Возник вопрос как сделать валидацию пересечения интервала дат? То есть если в БД есть запись интервал которой уже пересекается с интервалом который передает пользователь, то такую запись не записывать в БД. Можно это сделать при помощи SQL запроса

```
`WHERE `date_start` >= @end OR `date_finish` <= @start`
```

только как правильно создать валидацию?
Пытаюсь сделать так в моделе:

```
class Reserv < ActiveRecord::Base
    validate :dates_validate

private
    def dates_validate
      Reserv.where(["date_start < ? and date_finish > ?", date_start, date_finish]).nil?
    end
end
```

Во вьюхе

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Date start' %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :date_start %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Date finish' %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :date_finish %>
  </div>
```

Происходит абсолютно ничего если я добавляю 2 одинаковые записи (интервалы пересекаются), даже если условие в модели взять с отрицанием. То есть

```
!Reserv.where(["date_start < ? and date_finish > ?", date_start, date_finish]).nil?
```

**UPDATE**
набираю в консоли

```
2.2.1 :019 > p=Reserv.where(["date_start >= ? OR date_finish <= ?", "2016-01-05", "2016-01-10"]).count == 0
   (1.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "reservs" WHERE (date_start >= '2016-01-05' OR date_finish <= '2016-01-10')
 => false
```

А когда из приложения пытаюсь новую запись создать все проходит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.where` - возвращает объект класса ActiveRecord::Relation. А это уже не `nil`.

Метод для валидации будет таким:

```
def dates_validate
  Reserv.where(["date_start < ? and date_finish > ?", date_start, date_finish]).count == 0
end
```

Comment: Работает в консоли, а в приложении почему то нет.

Comment: @Павел А объекты какого класса в переменных `date_start` и `date_finish`?

Answer (score 0):

Можно и обычным [`#empty?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-empty-3F) воспользоваться:

```
Reserv.where(["date_start < ? and date_finish > ?", date_start, date_finish]).empty?
```

Ну и еще лучше писать с использованием [`Arel`](https://github.com/rails/arel):

```
reservs = Reserv.arel_table
Reserv.where(reservs[:date_start].lt(date_start).and(reservs[:date_start].gt(date_finish))).empty?
```